# Wrap multiple textviews to appear as one sentence

Tags: android

Consider the sentence

"**Mike** has commented on **Davids** review at **Pizza Planet**"

This sentence may wrap onto 2 lines, but I want the words "Mike", "Davids" and "Pizza Planet clickable items".

If I use separate TextViews for each of these word, and also for the non clickable words in between, How can I do this so that they wrap nicely onto 2 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spannable strings for your needs, check this out:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

SpannableString user = new SpannableString("Mike");
ClickableSpan userClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //click on user
    }
};
user.setSpan(userClickableSpan, 0, user.length(),
             SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

SpannableString commentedOnUser = new SpannableString("Davids");
ClickableSpan commentedOnUserClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //click on commentedOnUser
    }
};
commentedOnUser.setSpan(commentedOnUserClickableSpan, 0, commentedOnUser.length(), 
                        SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

SpannableString place = new SpannableString("Pizza Planet");
ClickableSpan placeClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //click on place
    }
};
place.setSpan(placeClickableSpan, 0, place.length(),
              SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
textView.setText(user);
textView.append(" is has commented on ");
textView.append(commentedOnUser);
textView.append(" review at ");
textView.append(place);
```

Now when it's all part of one TextView, use "\n" to break the line.

Comment: Is it possible to set the link colours, or underline them with this method?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, yes you can. override `updateDrawState` for the `ClickableSpan` object  (just after onClick) and you will be able to `setUnderlineText(boolean)` and  `setColor(int)`.